# Query car price with min and max selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

Trying to create a query which will display cars for sale, within a selected price range.

In the controller I have the following query which works.

```
public ActionResult index (string searchString)
{
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))

 {
 Car = Car.Where(s => s.Car.CarName.Contains(searchString));

 }
```

The MIn and Max for price I am having trouble implementing.

```
    public ActionResult index ( int min, int max, string searchString )
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))

      {

    Car = Car.Where(s => s.Car.CarName.Contains(searchString)
    && s.Price >= min && s.Price <= max).OrderBy(s => s.Price);


  ViewBag.minprice = min;
  ViewBag.maxprice = max;
```

In the view I have a corresponding drop down lists for the viewbags (Min and Max).

I am receiving an error:

An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.Parameter name: parameters

Comment: What's the trouble you're having?

Comment: The query looks odd.  Why do you have collection access syntax `s.Car.CarName` in the car name query, followed by a direct member access `s.Price`?  Shouldn't `s` be a car object with members of Price and CarName?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you're still using your old URL to access the index page. This old url doesn't contain the min and max arguments, which are required in your action, so it's blowing up. Also, if you'd made custom routes for the index, make sure you've rewritten them to include these two new arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a routing issue. You need to add something like the following to your global.asax page (RegisterRoutes method), before the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "IndexCompare", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{min}/{max}/{searchString}", // URL with parameters
      new
      {
          controller = "{controller}",
          action = "Index",
          min = 0,
          max = 0,
          searchString = UrlParameter.Optional
      } // Parameter defaults
);
```

So each time you change an Action signature, you need to make sure you have a route to match it.